# Tableau: How to outer join two tables from an Oracle database?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Typically, when I try to connect two tables in Tableau, a Venn diagram appears, and I can select the type of join I want (e.g., inner, outer, etc.). However, when connecting to an Oracle database and extracting tables from there, I am unable to join the two tables together.

When I click on the relational line, I have the PUID fields aligning, but they don't actually combine the tables in the preview below. This prohibits me from applying filters across the two datasets despite trying to join them. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you have above is actually the newer Tableau Relationship Builder.

If you will delete your 2nd table from above.

Then just simply right click on your first table. And select 'Open'

[image]

Now you will be presented with the database join feature you are accustom to seeing.
Just add in your next table as you would before and your venn-daigram will appear.

[image]

From here you can build your left outer, inner, right outer, full join just as before.